# Pulley question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, string

[image: this question]

I’ve noticed that in this question,we take the tension on each side as T1 and T2 even tho it’s the same string.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are told that the string does not slip on the pulley. Therefore there is friction $F$ between the string and the pulley. $F$ acting on the string is the difference between $T_1$ and $T_2$, and the equal and opposite force $F$ acting on the pulley gives the pulley a rotation acceleration $\dot \omega$.

You can write down equations of motion for the two masses and for the pulley. Together with the two relations

$T_1-T_2 = F\\a=R \dot \omega$

this gives you five equations in the five unknowns $T_1, T_2, F, \dot \omega, a$.